# AWS CloudFormation template - Required values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When we define parameters and refer it within Resources, the existence of parameter value is only checked upon stack creation; and if we fail to mention parameter value, then the stack creation fails and rollback with exception such as below

> Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name
> xxx does not exist. Rollback requested by user.

I know why and is clear from the [general requirement of parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) in AWS Cloud Formation document.

> • Each parameter must be assigned a value at runtime for AWS
> CloudFormation to successfully provision the stack.

However, what I would like to is to indicate users to when they fail to mention parameter values much before stack creation.

**Question**: Is there a way by which we could enforce to enter parameter's value before proceeding with stack creation ?

*For example, if we fail to mention stack name, console won't let you proceed. I would like something similar where it stop stack creation from proceeding if there a missing value. This image has nothing to do with my question; but to show you what I would like for my custom parameter to display in case of missing value*

**Update:** If someone like similar feature then following are sample solutions where parameter 'Name' constrain use to enter least a char before proceeding and 'SecuritygroupIngressCIDR' enforce a valid IP.

```
Parameters:
  Name:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
    MinLength: 1
    
  SecurityGroupIngressCIDR:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to communicate to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
```

[image: SampleVisual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paolo said, this is the way it is usually done. A complementary example would be:

```
Parameters:
  Name:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
    MinLength: 1
```

It is worth nothing that this will only error out when you hit `Create stack` which is the step 4 in the console. Not at the same time when you specify the parameters or stack name (Step 2).

Comment: Perfect and simple.

Comment: Guess you can get rid of `MinLength` if you specify `+` instead of `*` in the regex

Comment: @Paolo Yes. This is a more generic example. Its one of many possibilities which could be used to achieve similar outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `AllowedPattern` and `Constraint description` for the parameter.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html):

```
AllowedPattern
A regular expression that represents the patterns to allow for String types

ConstraintDescription
A string that explains a constraint when the constraint is violated.
```

Comment: Up-voting for your support.